# Reading in a 2D array as an argument in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i'm trying to pass a 2D char array into a function declared in a header file.

```
//Proj1Aux.h

#ifndef PROJ1AUX_H
#define PROJ1AUX_H

void makeBoard(char (*myBoard)[10], int boardSize);
void printBoard(char (*myBoard)[10], int boardSize);

#endif
```

I defined the functions as follows:

```
//Proj1Aux.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "Proj1Aux.h"

using namespace std;

void makeBoard(char (*myBoard)[10], int boardSize)
{
    //code
}

void printBoard(char (*myBoard)[10], int boardSize){

    //code
}
```

And then in my main function in another .cpp file:

```
//Proj1.cpp


#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Proj1Aux.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //code...
    //more code...

    char board[10][10];
    makeBoard(board, boardSize);
    printBoard(board, boardSize);

}
```

I'm a beginner at C++, and I dont have a firm grasp on pointers, or even header files.  I tried passing in the 2D array without any pointers, but the compiler gave me an error:

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'
```

So i tried putting in the pointers as listed above, and I get the same error

What do I do?  can anyone go through my code and tell me exactly what's wrong?

Comment: Don't include `.cpp` files in other `.cpp` files until you have a very, very solid understanding of header files. That's an advanced technique that will only get you into trouble for now.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you get and indicate which line you get it on?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't agree with itself.

```
char board[10][10];
```

This says board is a 2D array, 10 by 10.

```
makeBoard(board, boardSize);
```

This passes `board` to `makeBoard`, which will only work if `makeBoard`'s first parameter is compatible with a 10 by 10, 2D array.

```
void makeBoard(char (*myBoard)[10], int boardSize)
```

But this says the first parameter to `makeBoard` is a pointer to a 1D array. That's nothing like a 2D array -- they're completely incompatible. Arrays are compatible with pointers to their first elements. So a pointer to a 1D array has two levels of indirection -- the pointer leads you to a 1D array, which decays into a pointer to the first element. A 2D array has one level of indirection -- the array decays into a pointer to its first element.

So, which is it? Is the parameter a pointer to the contents, or a pointer to a pointer to the contents?

Why not just use `std::vector` instead of arrays?